# How can I center my div content responsively with sidebar and top menu on the same page?

Tags: php, html, css, bootstrap-5, center

I'm trying to center my div content responsively with a sidebar menu and a top menu using bootstrap. But my div content is placed at the bottom of my page when I require the side-menu file and I don't know why. I'm not using any CSS file, just Bootstrap 5.2, but if your solution requires CSS that's okay.

**INDEX**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>TESTE</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $base_url . 'assets/css/bootstrap.min.css'; ?>">

    <!-- FontAwesome CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $base_url . 'assets/css/all.min.css'; ?>">
</head>
<body>

    <!-- NAVIGATION -->
    <?php require 'application/views/menu/side-menu.php'; ?>


    <div class="container justify-content-center">
        <!-- AGENDAMENTOS -->
        <div class="row mt-5 me-4">
            <div class="col-md-12 offset-md-auto">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h4 class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-calendar-days"></i> TO DO - 27 </h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- end agendamentos -->


        <!-- FEITOS -->
        <div class="row mt-5">
            <div class="col-md-12 offset-md-auto">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h4 class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> DONE - 27 </h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- end feitos -->
    </div>



    <!-- Bootstrap Bundle JS -->
    <script src="<?php echo $base_url . 'assets/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js'; ?>"></script>

    <!-- Fontawesome JS -->
    <script src="<?php echo $base_url . 'assets/js/all.min.js'; ?>"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**SIDE MENU**

```
<div class="d-inline-block">
    <nav class="bg-dark text-white" style="max-height: 100%; height: 100vw; max-width: 10vw;">
        <div class="navbar-default sidebar" role="navigation">
            <div class="sidebar-nav navbar-collapse">
                <ul>
                    <li>a</li>

                    <li>b</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

This is what it was supposed to look like, but with the sidebar:
[image]

And this is what happens when I require my sidebar file:
[image]

I tried using `position-absolute` and `d-inline-block`, which resulted on other pages, but this isn't working on this one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap is build on/with Flexbox. So a good solution for you is to use their Flex Utility classes to make the layout.

##### Explaining the solution

When dealing with elements that should stretch the entire viewport height it's good practice to set a `min-height` of `100vh` to `html` and `body`.

*Note in the CSS I also added `min-height: -webkit-fill-available`. They are commented out because they don't work in the iFrame, at least for me they don't. I recommend removing the comment block if you use this code; they're useful because Safari (iOS mostly) handles `100vh` a little different than the other browsers which can cause some issues.*

I then made the `body` a flex container so its direct children elements (flex items) will stack horizontally (by default). I used the class `d-md-flex` so all elements will stack vertically below the medium break point. Use `d-flex` if you want your sidebar to always stick to the left.

*If you don't want `body` to be flex, a 'wrapper' `<div class="d-md-flex">...</div>` that spans all the (necessary) elements  is a good alternative. Just add the CSS for it, setting it to `height: 100%;` or `100vh`.*

Speaking of sidebar; making it flex will now make it stretch the whole viewport, since it's a flex item of a flex container (`body`) that has a height of `100vh`.

And that's it. Snippet is best viewed using the full page option.

```css
html {
  /*min-height: -webkit-fill-available;*/
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  /*height: -webkit-fill-available;*/
  max-height: 100vh;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-MV7K8+y+gLIBoVD59lQIYicR65iaqukzvf/nwasF0nqhPay5w/9lJmVM2hMDcnK1OnMGCdVK+iQrJ7lzPJQd1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.1/js/all.min.js" integrity="sha512-rpLlll167T5LJHwp0waJCh3ZRf7pO6IT1+LZOhAyP6phAirwchClbTZV3iqL3BMrVxIYRbzGTpli4rfxsCK6Vw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt">

<head></head>

<body class="d-md-flex">

  <!-- SIDEBAR -->
  <nav class="d-flex flex-row flex-column flex-shrink-0 p-3 text-bg-dark" style="min-width: 10vw;">
    hello
  </nav>
  <!-- END SIDEBAR -->

  <!-- MAIN -->
  <main class="container">
    <div class="row mt-5 row-cols-1 row-cols-md-3 g-4 justify-content-center">

      <div class="col">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-calendar-days"></i> TO DO - 27 </h4>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> DONE - 27</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </main>
  <!-- END MAIN -->

</body>
</html>
```

**Your card layout**

I changed your two cards layout to make it easier to control how they behave, using row columns and the gap `g-*` utility class. **It has no effect on how the sidebar behaves**, so if it's of no use; just ignore it.